# Fractions for variables names in Julia

Tags: variables, julia, naming-conventions, brackets, ijulia-notebook

In julia you can write subscripts by `\_` for variable names. I was wondering if there is anything similar for writing fractions in variable names. Something like `\frac{}{}` in LaTeX. I understand this may be harder as it takes two arguments. If there is none, I will use `/`. But in this case I would like to use some enclosures to make clear what is being differentiated. I assume `()` is not usable? `[]` or `{}` would be ok?

Comment: I guess `/` is probably not usable either...

Comment: I guess I can use `\div`

Comment: can also use `\llbracket` etc, but now its too long defeats the purpose...

Comment: but i guess its just not possible to fit too much vertically in a single line...

Comment: just to let you know, I really cherish the freedom in variable naming. Naming variables is becoming a real headache

Comment: `\not` is probably better than `\div`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subscripts or other non-latin names you see in Julia code are just normal unicodes the same as "regular" names. the LaTeX commands are only a function of Julia REPL to remember and input them.

As for unicode, in principle you can represent some simple fractions like `⁽²⁺ⁱ⁾⁄₍ₛ₊ₜ₎`, using the `⁄` (U+2044 Fraction slash) symbol and [subscripts and superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts). The rendering depends on your font, but do not expect a verticle layout in any current fonts.

However, Julia recognizes `⁄` (U+2044 Fraction slash, not the `/` in your keyboard) as "invalid character" when used along during parsing. The same applies to `\not`, which can only be used in conjunction with some operators, so it's not an option too.

As for the brackets and the normal `/`, they are operators and are parsed differently. However, there is an (ugly) way to circumvent this: you can use macros to bypass the parsing and use strings as variable names. For example:

```
julia> macro n_str(name)
           esc(Symbol(name))
       end
@n_str (macro with 1 method)

julia> n"∂(2x + 3)/∂x" = 2
2

julia> 2n"∂(2x + 3)/∂x"
4
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the detailed response. Sorry I'm actually not familiar with macros. So how was `n_str` used?

Comment: Hi, just like in the example, you cound use `n"anything"` as a variable, so the allowed characters extend to anything that can appear in a string, at the cost of `n""` around the name. [this is the document](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/index.html#Non-Standard-String-Literals-1) for non-standard string literals, and you might need to read the whole page to fully understand how macro works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for \diagup (`⁄`).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34831524)